# Merge with repeated row.names in R

Tags: r

I am trying to merge two data frames with repeated row.names and it gives me the error : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column.

Given the code below, I want my newly merged data frame to have two rows with "a" "100" "chicken and "a" "100" "beef". Do anyone know whats the easiest way to do it if I have multiple repetitions?

```
name   <- c("a", "b", "c")
height <- c(100, 150, 160)
x      <- data.frame(name, height)

name   <- c("a", "a", "b")
food   <- c("chicken", "beef", "salad")
y      <- data.frame(name, food)

merge(x,y,by = "name")
```

My desired result:

```
name  <- c("a", "a", "b", "c")
height <- c(100, 100, 150, 160)
food   <- c("chicken", "beef", "salad", "NA")
data.frame(name, height, food)
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try adding `all = TRUE` to `merge`?

Comment: `merge(x, y, by = "name", all.x=TRUE)` or `require(dplyr); left_join(x, y, by = "name")`

Comment: You don't even need `by`, you can just do `merge(x, y, all = TRUE)`

Comment: @RichardScriven - in this case yes, but risky potentially in other cases.

Comment: Just to be contrary... these are NOT duplicated rownames. Duplicated rownames do NOT appear in properly constructed R dataframes.